# Links (href) not relative to application in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I am in the process of changing a project which used a simple java HTTPServer on port 8080 to that which uses the Spring MVC servlet framework.

There are lots of links in the application like so:

```
<a href=\"/rule\">Manage rules</a><br/>
```

Which worked fine using requests such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/send
```

However, these now don't work unless I put the servlet name in front like so:

```
"<a href=\"/ServletName/rule\">Manage rules</a><br/>"
```

Just wondering is there any way around this, or is it a matter of just changing all the href links to add the servlet name in front of them?

Note that I dont have to add the servlet name in my @RequestMapping calls at the start of methods, its only links that are the problem. E.g. this works fine without adding the servlet name in front

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: All href links are relative to the current context. If you are using Apache Server you can configure your apache server to include the servlet name in every request before it hits your app server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use JSPs in your view layer, use a tag library that has a link tag (or write one yourself). Basically, the link tag has to create the url by doing

```
HttpServletResponse.encodeURL(originalUrl)
```

The [`<c:url>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) tag in JSTL does that, but it only generates the URL, not the link tag, but it can get you there like this:

```
<c:url value="your/relative/url" var="somevar" />
<a href="${somevar}">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not using JSPs I'm afraid. I thought there might have been a way to do this through the xml files -  maybe rewrite URLs in the web.xml or applicationContext.xml or something?

Comment: @Rory well what *do* you use in you view layer? Don't tell me you are doing direct output from java code.

Comment: Yep..using the HttpServletResponse parameter to do httpServletResponse.getWriter.write("<a href=\"/send/rulepush?ip=" + ip + "\">);

Comment: @Rory well then may the lord have mercy with your soul. But you need something like this: `httpServletResponse.getWriter.write("<a href=\"" + httpServletResponse.encodeURL("/send/rulepush?ip=" + ip) + "\">);`